# Calculation of Schwarzschild Normal Vectors

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors

I just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly here:

For $ds^2=-(1-\frac{2m}{r})dt^2+\frac{1}{(1-\frac{2m}{r})}dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2$,

$n_\alpha=(-\sqrt{1-\frac{2m}{r}},0,0,0)$.

So then for a new version of the metric, $ds^2=-(1-\frac{2m}{r})dt'^2-2\sqrt{\frac{2m}{r}}dt'dr+dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2$,

$n_\alpha=(-\sqrt{1-\frac{2m}{r}},\frac{\partial t}{\partial r}n_t,0,0)$.

Does all of this look right?

Comment: What is the definition of the normal vector ?  And how you obtain the new metric, from the normal vector ?

Comment: When I say unit normal I mean the unit vector orthogonal to the hypersurface. Also, I already have the new metric, so my goal is not to obtain it.